# Memory Issues in R when trying to run models in parallel

Tags: r, performance, memory, r-caret

I am trying to use the 'caret' package to run some predictions on a dataset the size of approximately 28000 rows and 58 columns of all numeric data. (this is the mash social news dataset on UCI dataset repository if you are wondering, after taking 75% of it for the training dataset)

I'm trying to run some classification models on a 'yes'/'no' if the number of page views exceeded 1400.

This the general input I am using

```
library(caret)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl<-detectCores() *.5
registerDoParallel(cl)

ctrl = trainControl(
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
    classProbs = TRUE,
    savePredictions = 'final',  # change to TRUE for all
    method = 'cv',
    number = kfolds,
    repeats = repeats_folds,
    verboseIter = TRUE,
    seeds = seeds,
    allowParallel =TRUE,
    preProcOptions = c('scale','center')
)




"train" is the first 58 or so columns exlcuding a couple of irrelevant ones



mod_rf = train(
    x = train, y = target,
    method = 'rf',
    trControl =  ctrl,
    tuneGrid = grid_rf,
    # tuneLength = NULL,
    metric=measurement
)
```

However, I am having what appears to be major issues when it comes to generating the actual prediction.  Either my computer crashes with a popup on Rstudio saying it needs to terminate or it just doesn't seem to finish.

I have a 16gb state of the art Macbook Pro.  Is there anything I could or should be doing to improve my performance?  My number of cores used here is 4 instead of 8 since that slowed rest of my laptop down.

Comment: Try using method = "parRF". Otherwise randomforest will not run in parallel.

Comment: Try using `method = "ranger"` or one of the other high performance random forest packages. Keep in mind that you will always be increasing the memory needs _X_-fold with you run in parallel using _X_ workers, Also, look in Activity Monitor before you run in parallel to assess how much memory your data are taking up prior to running random forest.

Comment: @phiver Using parallel processing the way that he is will run the model tuning in parallel but not the underlying RF model. This is generally faster than tuning sequentially and running each RF model in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using registerDoParallel incorrectly. Try using:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
```